# I want to execute shell script through prometheus alert manger when ever alert manager triggers script should execute

Tags: alert, slack

```
[centos@exe93-aws-mum:/etc/release/exops_nodemon/prometheus]# cat alertmanager.yaml
      global:
      slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'

    route:
      group_by: ['instance', 'severity']
      group_wait: 30s
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 3h
      routes:
      - match:
          alertname: InstanceDown
      receiver: 'alert-team'
      - name: 'executor'
      webhook_configs:
      - cmd: bash /etc/release/exops_nodemon/prometheus/test.sh
    receivers:
      - name: 'alert-team'
        slack_configs:
        - channel: "#sase-support"
          text: "summary: {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}\ndescription: {{ .CommonAnnotations.description }}"
    #- cmd: bash /etc/release/exops_nodemon/prometheus/test.sh
```

''
I have return shell script it contains curl command to execute stackstorm api and it needs work such way that when ever alert manager triggers for to send notification on slack my script also need to be executed .Please help me where I can add block in alertmanager.yaml!
''

Comment: Please some help on the above issue.Thanks advance

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. 
 - Are you able to configure the trigger?
 - Are you able to verify the trigger is activated?
 - Are you having problems with your script?
 - What action(s) did you take, what did you expect and what actually happened?

Answer (score 0):

Using Slack with the Alertmanager
Previously we looked at how to use the Prometheus Alertmanager with Pagerduty. The Alertmanager supports more than just sending pages, there's integrations with popular chat applications too. Let's look at how to integrate with Slack.

Slack Setup
The Alertmanager uses the Incoming Webhooks feature of Slack, so first we need to set that up.

Go to the Incoming Webhooks page in the App Directory and click "Install" (or "Configure" and then "Add Configuration" if it's already installed):

[image-for the webhook configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HA1e.png)

You can then configure your new webhook. Choose the default channel to post to, and then add the integration:

[Imae ref2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd6H5.png)

WEBHOOK_URL=XXXX  # Substitute in your Webhook URL here.
wget https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/releases/download/v0.8.0/alertmanager-0.8.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xzf alertmanager-0.8.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz
cd alertmanager-*

cat < alertmanager.yml
route:
group_by: [cluster]

## If an alert isn't caught by a route, send it slack.

receiver: slack_general
routes:

## Send severity=slack alerts to slack.

- match:
  severity: slack
  receiver: slack_general

receivers:

- name: slack_general
  slack_configs:

  - api_url: $WEBHOOK_URL
    channel: '#general'
    EOF
    ./alertmanager &

Notifications in Slack:
[notification in slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUKPH.png)

Article ref: https://www.robustperception.io/using-slack-with-the-alertmanager